# Why pandas.eval() string comparison returns False

Tags: python, pandas, eval

Could someone explain me why this simple piece of code returns `False`? That's probably pretty simple, but I don't understand why it behaves like that:

```py
import pandas as pd

eval_string = '"abc"=="abc"'
print(pd.eval(eval_string, parser='pandas'))  # False
```

Note that it I try to use string's **eq**() function instead, it behaves as I expect.

Can be run online here: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zhsnud82

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.eval` [does not support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#supported-syntax) scalar comparison.

> This Python syntax is **not** allowed:
>
> - Expressions
>
>   - ...
>   - Boolean expressions consisting of only scalar values

Pass it unsupported syntax, and Pandas makes no promises about what you'll get back. (That includes not promising to give wrong results. The fact that `pandas.eval('4==4')` happens to give `True` doesn't mean it's supported.)

`pandas.eval` is a specialized tool for evaluating specific sorts of expressions on large dataframes. It should not be used for running general Python code.

Comment: `pd.eval(4==4)` is valid

Comment: @rkochar: That's undefined behavior, first because you're passing it a `True` boolean instead of the string `'4==4'`, and second because `'4==4'` would be a scalar comparison. The fact that `pandas.eval(4==4)` and `pandas.eval('4==4')` happen to both give `True` doesn't mean it's supported. Pandas makes no promises about what will happen.